# Why do all my MacVim color schemes look wrong?

Tags: vim, macvim

I am having a problem with my MacVim color schemes. I have 'syntax on' in my .vimrc and I work mostly with Python.

As an example, I have attached a screenshot of what the "default" color scheme looks like in MacVim to me. I am having this problem with varying degrees of color differences for all the different schemes. Whenever I find a scheme I like online, it never looks like it does in the screenshot.

Any ideas on what the problem is?

[image: here]

Comment: Does the Mac-Terminal support 256-colors per default?

Comment: MacVim is Mac OS X's equivalent of GVim.

Comment: Could you show the content of your `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: [Here is my vimrc](http://pastebin.com/Ua8BBibc)

Comment: Funny enough, the only webpage that Google has indexed with the phrase [`desertmarc vim colorscheme`](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=desertmarc&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=QJd&channel=fs&sa=X&ei=UNBCT_W6H-SjiQKsvey8AQ&ved=0CBsQvgUoAA&q=desertmarc+vim+colorscheme&nfpr=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e6faae0b5da64255&biw=1209&bih=1116) is _your_ pastebin. Where can this `desertmarc` scheme be found? That'd make reproducing your problem far easier. :)

Comment: It's a homemade colorscheme. But just for reference, you can switch that line to anything. Changing it to colorscheme=default gives the colorscheme shown in the image in my original post. However, I just noticed something interesting. Colorschemes look different if they are set in the vimrc versus being manually set (:colorscheme default) after MacVim has loaded. Really weird.

Comment: Thank you, @kamek, your comment helped me a lot. Color scheme should be set via `.vimrc` script to be rendered correctly in MacVim.

Answer (score 5):

Many themes provide modes for both dark background colors and light background colors. If you'd like to keep using this theme, try running:

```
:set background=light
```

Most of the themes I've seen were designed with a dark background and lighter text in mind -- I personally find a mostly-black screen easier on my eyes than a mostly-white screen -- so perhaps you just need to change the background color to something dark. In which case, you'd then want to run:

```
:set background=dark
```

Comment: Although this did change the colours, it did not correct them. They are just different, but still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in ~/.gvimrc, look at what it does with the highlights (such as `highlight NonText guibg=grey80`). I've just placed them in an `if !exists("stupid_colors")`.